# Cannot read attribute from JSON element

Tags: automated-tests, karate

I'm trying to fetch the value from an attribute in the payload but Karate throws an error or simply doesn't fetch the value.

I've created a simplified version of my code to make it easier to understand.

```
* def lists = [{@id: 1, type: 'video'}, {@id: 2, type: 'image'}]
* def ser = {@id: 2, type: '#string'}

* def foundAt = []
* def fun = function(x, i){ if (karate.match(x, ser).pass) foundAt.add(i) }
* eval karate.forEach(lists, fun)
* def storeId = lists[foundAt[0]].@id
* def storeType = lists[foundAt[0]].type
* print storeId
* print storeType
```

**print storeType** will print the value as expected but **print storeId** will print the following error message:

```
javascript evaluation failed: lists[foundAt[0]].@id, <eval>:1:18 Expected ident but found error
lists[foundAt[0]].@id
                  ^ in <eval> at line number 1 at column nu*mber 18
```

I expect the value '2' to be printed but clearly I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One small change will do the trick since `@` is a "bad" character for JSON key-names:

```
* def storeId = lists[foundAt[0]]['@id']
```

Here's also a suggested simplification to your code:

```
* def fun = function(x, i){ return karate.match(x, ser).pass }
* def found = karate.filter(lists, fun)
* def storeId = found[0]['@id']
* def storeType = found[0].type
* print storeId
* print storeType
```